# How to use ng-change if value is not selected from ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If i dont select value from dropdown and click on startRecording button it throw error  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined` any idea how can i resolve this problem using ng-change directive of angularJs ?

main.html

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedFileSize" ng-options="item as item.value for item in FileSizeOptions" ng-change="onSizeChange()"><option value="">Select</option></select>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="startRecording()">Start Recording</button>
```

ctrl.js

```
 $scope.FileSizeOptions = [{size: 1, value: "1MB"}, {size: 2, value: "2MB"}, {size: 3, value: "3MB"}, {size: 4, value: "4MB"}, {size: 5, value:"5MB"}];

$scope.onSizeChange = function() {
    $scope.maxMb = $scope.selectedFileSize.size;
    $scope.maxBytes = 1000 * 1000 * $scope.maxMb;
    $scope.max = $scope.maxBytes;
    $scope.FileSizeString = $scope.selectedFileSize.value;
    console.log('FileSize', $scope.maxMb);
}
$scope.startRecording = function() {
        if ($scope.selectedFileSize.size) { //logic here 
       } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if it is undefined or not. If nothing is selected then it will throw this error unless you put this code in:

```
    if($scope.selectedFileSize!=undefined){
        if ($scope.selectedFileSize.size) { //logic here 
       } 
    }
```

Comment: I've put it into this Plunkr and I'm not getting it anymore. https://plnkr.co/edit/n1tSfj2YJMeBZNZCSAF3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $scope.selectedFileSize.size will be undefined, because you did not select any.

1, You should only do this: if($scope.selectedFileSize) because you only have to make sure if the ng-model (selectedFileSize) is defined or not.

2, disable/hide the button until one of the items are not selected.
In this case you should use ng-if or ng-show/ng-hide on the button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="selectedFileSize" ng-click="startRecording()">Start Recording</button>
```

the ng-if directive expects an expression, it means that if selectedFileSize is defined it will be true, and the button will show up, if selectedFileSize is not defined (on init) it will not appear.

Comment: Well in case of ng-if it will show button when i will have value in ng-model but if again select default value that is `select` in options it is throwing same error again

Comment: I made a working example.
https://plnkr.co/edit/jJKiTKHoUeGPg9GyPUvk?p=preview
I only changed the one as described in my first point.

Comment: so what is the difference you are exactly doing same thing as i mentioned in question, but i am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
if ($scope.selectedFileSize && $scope.selectedFileSize.size) {
               //logic here 
            }
```